# How do have my docker image run apache as a service

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've built a docker image to run apache. I've built it from a ubuntu base image so that I could set the apache and php versions I wanted. I've added a `CMD` to the end of my docker file to run apache in the foreground.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2 && \
    apt-get update && \

    ....

WORKDIR /

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl","-DFOREGROUND"]
```

I'm trying to run the container using docker-compose (along with some other services). However the container exits immediately. The same happens if run the image with the `docker` command.

```
docker run my_image
docker ps
```

Interestingly if I run it with `docker run -it my_image`, then the container starts and I'm taken into a bash shell. (I believe the default CMD on the ubuntu base image I'm using is bash).

Am I missing something? How do I write my Dockerfile so that apache runs as a service on the image?

Comment: What does `docker logs <CONTAINER>` say?

Comment: "I'm trying to run the container from a Dockerfile (along with some other services)" - Not sure that makes sense? How do you mean?

Comment: "Interestingly if I run it with docker run -it my_image" - Weird, can you post the whole Dockerfile and how you're trying to run it (the various ways) please?

Comment: @johnharris85 - thanks, my bad - I meant to say I'm trying to run the container with docker-compose. I've updated my question. I may post more info when I get back to my desk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are getting a bash shell when running your image, it sounds like your `CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl","-DFOREGROUND"]` isn't taking effect.

Double check that your `docker build` command succeeded, and that you are running the built image and not some other image.

Here's an example Dockerfile, the relevant `docker build` output (specifically the `CMD` step), and an example of it running:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install apache2 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

CMD apachectl -DFOREGROUND
$ docker build -t myapache .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 2fa927b5cdd3
Step 2 : RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install apache2 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f766fd84056d
Step 3 : CMD apachectl -DFOREGROUND
 ---> Running in 2814d231e50e
 ---> 774b579e43ce
Removing intermediate container 2814d231e50e
Successfully built 774b579e43ce
$ r run -d --name myapache -p 80:80 myapache
4718994f1669306c64ac6846f4e0f87aa15a63a888ca7d5c8ba711f39379db57
$ http://localhost:80/

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <!--
    Modified from the Debian original for Ubuntu
    Last updated: 2014-03-19
    See: https://launchpad.net/bugs/1288690
...
```

Comment: That's it - the container I was running wasn't from the Dockerfile I thought it was - checking the output of the build was what I needed to identify that. Thanks @programmerq!

Comment: CMD apachectl -DFOREGROUND was my problem. Now it works, thanks :-)